# Discrete Mathematics - Recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Given the following question by my professor:

```
 Recursively define the set of natural numbers divisible by 3.
```

My answer:

```
Basis clause: 0 is in S.

Inductive clause: For any natural number x, x*3 is in S.

Extremal clause: Nothing is in S unless it is obtained from the Basis and Inductive clause.
```

My inductive clause is apparently wrong, and I cannot figure out any other way to define all the natural numbers divisible by 3.

Any help on why I might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In order for it to be **recursive**, you cannot say $\forall x \in \Bbb{Z}$ in the inductive clause; rather, you must say something with $\forall x \in \mathcal{S}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition defines the elements of the set in terms of the natural numbers, rather than in terms of the other elements of the set.

Here's a recursive definition along the lines of what he was probably looking for:

- **Basis Clause:** $0$ is in $S$.
- **Inductive Clause:** For any $x$ in $S$, $x+3$ is in $S$
- **Extremal Clause:** Nothing is in $S$ unless it is obtained by the above two clauses

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Omnomnomnom's answer.

Basis Clause: $0$ is in S.

Inductive Clause: For any $x$ in S, $x+1$ is not in S, $x+2$ is not in S, $x+3$ is in S

Exercise for the reader:
Show that all integers are decided.